# implementing mediaElement.js results in error

Tags: javascript, joomla, media-player, media

I'm trying to implement the mediaElement.js solution in a Joomla website I'm working on but i'm running into some problems. The following error is haunting me in my dreams :P:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mediaelementplayer'
```

I would assume that /mediaelement-and-player.min.js but the Console does not display any errors except the one already mentioned.

I have added the following to my template head:

```
$this->API->addJS($this->API->URLtemplate() . '/mediaElement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js');
$this->API->addJS($this->API->URLtemplate() . '/mediaElement/build/jquery.js');
```

This results in the right link when the page loads so I guess that won't be the problem.

In the body of my article I've added the following code:

```
<video id="youtube1" width="640" height="360">
  <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" type="video/youtube" >
</video>

<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#youtube1').mediaelementplayer();
   });

</script>
```

Eventhough this code is from the examples provided it results in the error mentioned before.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the mediaelement.js file loaded in the final HTML?

Comment: no, just mediaelement-and-player.min.js

Comment: But next to that. I'm positive about the files being loaded in as I have stated in my comment to Lodder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if the file is being included properly as I can't see the website, so try this to include **jquery.js** and the **mediaelement-and-player.min.js**

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
//check to see if jquery is already being loaded
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/template_name/mediaElement/build/jquery.js");
}
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/template_name/mediaElement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js");
```

don't forget to change **template_name** within that path in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for the example but I'm absolutely positive the file gets loaded as I check it in chrome by inspecting the HEAD and clicking on the provided link which succesfully brings me to both .JS files. Next to that the console does not give any warnings or errors indicating that the file load failed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the input.

I have found the problem and solution :D.

removing this line from the head.php

```
$this->API->addJS($this->API->URLtemplate() . '/mediaElement/build/jquery.js');
```

Solved my problem.

I guess this is because jQuery was already loaded by the template I'm using.

I hope this will safe someone else a headace in the future.

Happy coding!

Comment: That's odd as the code I provided in my answer is to check if jquery is already being loaded. If it isn't, it loads it. If it is, it doesn't load it.

Comment: Hey! it's true if I implement the check the way you did it also fixes the problem. Thanks man!